# multiprocessing.pool.Pool string back to object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to send a pool to a string and then get it back later to close/join the pool. Here's an example of how to duplicate what I'm doing:

```
import multiprocessing

num_of_p = 5
_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_of_p)
pool_string = str(_pool)
```

Is there a way to turn `pool_string` back into a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool object`?

Comment: Not possible. Why are you building this string in the first place?

Comment: I'm creating a web tool using flask, that streams information about what's happening while the tool is running to the dom of the page. at the end of the run, because i was using a generator to return a stream of print statements, I couldn't find a good way to close/join the pool. So at the moment I stream a redirect into the dom at the end of the runs to a new location in the app passing a qouted version of the pool string. The hope was that I could use exec() or something to get it back from the string. oh course, that didn't work.

Comment: I've since replaced this with a global that handles all the pools based on uuid of the run, but I was just curious if it was possible.

Comment: I remember what I originally wanted here. I was hoping the "object at 0x000001F8495BCC18" could somehow be used to create a new object that pointed to that object reference. I'm sorry that I failed to communicate this, when I first asked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a misunderstand of the dynamic typing of python.

First, `pool_string` was never an object of the class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`

You just have called its`__str__` method:

```
>>> pool_string
'<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x000001F8495BCC18>'
>>> dir(_pool)[26]
'__str__'
>>> _pool.__str__()
'<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x000001F8495BCC18>'
```

That was and string from the beginning to the end of your script.

Maybe you just want to make another reference to your actual `_pool`:

```
_pool2 = _pool
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to help.

Comment: Reading your comment about your Flask web tool, I suppose that you want to transfer the state of that pool or something but you may have encountered with this problem `NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled` I hope that somebody outhere could real help you.

Comment: I remember what I originally wanted here. I was hoping the "object at 0x000001F8495BCC18" could somehow be used to create a new object that pointed to that object reference. I'm sorry that I failed to communicate this, when I first asked.